# Going from OpenGL ES 1.1 to ES 2 just for performance issues

Tags: performance, opengl-es

I have read a lot about the pros and cons of going from ES 1.1 to ES 2 and I just wanted to clarify one thing. The game I have made, using ES 1.1, has performance issues (runs slow and low FPS) on some devices and I just wanted to know if I make the change to ES 2 would it help? The game makes use of lighting, blending and texturing. I am not wishing to jazz it up or change effects in anyway, just simply increase performance.

Comment: Do you have any idea about why your application isn't running as fast as you would like?

Comment: @Nicol. I'm run about 50 to hundred drawelemnts() each time in Ondraw(). Should I not be doing this? (I do need to redraw them as they are all moving some how.)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what kind of performance increase you could expect between GLES 1.1 and GLES 2.0 without knowing how you built your renderer. *Ideally*, yes, you will see a performance increase by going to GLES 2.0. This may be because whatever platform you're using is handling GLES 1.1 APIs through GLES 2.0, but again, it depends a lot on what you're doing.

I'd recommend first profiling your program to see what's causing the performance issues before you decide it's an issue with your choice of API. It might be because you're constantly reloading some textures or you're not doing state management properly or maybe you're for some reason just doing something that's blocking the rest of your code. Again, without knowing your code, it's not really possible for anyone to say for sure that your game's performance will improve just by changing APIs.

Comment: When you say continuously reloading textures, do you mean recalling bindtexture() or do you mean load them in, as the later I do at startup only. Also I guess it could be bad coding by me, however I believed it was that I was calling drawelement() about 50 to 100 times in Ondraw() and some lighter powered phones could not handle it.

Comment: Again, profile your code. Without knowing what you've done, I can't make any reasonable guesses as to where your performance is dying. That said, if you can minimize the amount of state change, that's usually good. This includes calling `BindTexture`.